# Average rating calculated from previous rating and voters count

Tags: php, math

I need to calcuated average score of something and while everything was so clear when I started this job, my brain is protesting after long hours of programming.

Voters can vote *from 1 to 100*.

Ive got 2 values in database:

- Number of votes - *lets make it 10 for the sake of example*
- Average rating of previous votes - *let make it 100, everybody has voted 100 so far*

11th person will vote *75*.

I now need to calculate:

- Count of voters
- New average rating

---

```
$voters_count = 10;
$average_rating = 100;

$new_rating = 75;

$voters_count++;
$new_average_rating = '???';
```

Help me to overcome my brainfart. **How to calculate new average rating?**

Comment: The "median" is not the "average." I think you mean the "mean."

Comment: $new_average_rating = (($voters_count - 1) * $average_rating + $new_rating) / $voters_count. Simple math problem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/how-to-add-and-subtract-values-from-an-average

Comment: This is not math worthy - it's knowing the definition average and using high school algebra, nothing more.

Comment: @SeanBright Thank you for pointing that out. Im not very strong in English when it comes to specific math terms. It's even hard to explain now - just the average rating from the group who has voted.. Omg, this is hard to explain.

Comment: @duffymo Well, it's definately not an insult because high school graduates are usually at the peak of their knowledge, at least where I live. :)

Comment: Not meant to be an insult, except to say that it's another example of a programmer with a shockingly low mathematical capability.  All human beings need to know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute a new weighted average from the previous average weighted with the previous vote count and the new voting:

```
$new_average_rating = ($old_voters_count * $average_rating + $new_rating) /
   $voters_count
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should store every vote, because you may need more than a running average, but given the information you have you can create a running average by multiplying the number of votes by the existing average and then adding the new value and then dividing by the new number of votes.

New Average = ((Old Average * Old Number of Votes) + New Vote)/ New Number of Votes.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing more than simple algebra.

The average is the sum of values divided by the number of values:

```
average = sum/number
```

Multiply both sides by number to calculate the sum:

```
sum = average*number
```

Add on a new value and the new average becomes:

```
average(new) = (sum(old)*number + value(new))/(number+1)
```

You can repeat this for as many new values as you wish.